# For loop runs infinitely why?

Tags: c

for loop runs infinitely and it prints 1 infinitely when I run the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
int i,n;
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i+2){
printf("%d",i);
}
getch();
}
```

If the input of n= 10

**Actual Output:**

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.......
```

**Expected Output:**

```
13579
```

I want to know why 1 is printed infinitely.

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `... i<=n; i+2){` - `i` never changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i+2` does not change `i`, you want `i += 2` or `i = i + 2`